# Cannot set up WS2812B LEDs with bit banging and ATmega328P at 16MHz

Tags: atmega328p, ws2812b, bit-bang

I have an ATmega328P (16MHz extern, GBoard with SIM900 module). I bought 10 LEDs with WS2812B module. My ATmega works with 3.3V but for LEDs I need 5V so I decided to connect [TXB0104](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/txb0104-level-shifter-hookup-guide/all).

I connected TXB0104 with C1 output pin from ATmega. My LEDs work randomly. I cannot set proper color and brightness using [`light_ws2812` library](https://github.com/cpldcpu/light_ws2812/tree/master/light_ws2812_AVR).

My code is very simple. I know I have 10 diodes but for now I just want to test first in the row. What is the problem this doesn't work? Maybe TXB0104 is not convenient for this purpose? I know `light_ws2812` uses bit banging and assembler code. Maybe it is too fast for TXB0104? By the way, I didn't connect OE pins of TXB0104 but it should be fine anyway.

```
#define F_CPU 16000000
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include "light_ws2812.h"



struct cRGB led[1];

int main(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
            led[0].r = 255;
            led[0].b = 00;
            led[0].g = 0;
            ws2812_setleds(led, 1);
            _delay_ms(500);

            led[0].r = 0;
            led[0].b = 255;
            led[0].g = 0;
            ws2812_setleds(led, 1);
            _delay_ms(500);

            led[0].r = 0;
            led[0].b = 00;
            led[0].g = 255;
            ws2812_setleds(led, 1);
            _delay_ms(500);
    }
}
```

---

**The problem is TXB0104! I connected my GBoard directly to WS2812B.It works as expected.**

Can anybody tell me if this is because 16MHz is too fast for TXB0104 or maybe OE pins should be somehow connected?

I cannot use 3,3V from GBoard but some converter instead. @user263983, you suggested to use BJT. Which one should I use for this purpose? I'm newbie. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not need bidirectional level shifter. Just one BJT is enough.

Comment: do you have an oscilloscope? that would be great for troubleshooting whether it's a hardware or software problem

Comment: No, I don't have oscilloscope. With this source code my first and second led light up randomly. It means 24 bits are spread to 2 diodes - "too long" signal. I reduced my parameters of number of clocks but the result is still random.
Based on source code for 16MHz there shoud be following number of clock cycles:

  #define w_zerocycles    7 // 16*0,4 = 6,4

  #define w_onecycles     13 // 16*0,8 = 12,8

  #define w_totalcycles   20 //16*1,25 =20

Comment: have you tried one of the example sketches for your library? have you tried a different library (e.g. Adafruit_NeoPixel) and is examples? If that works you know you have a software problem.